# Matching sql date with .NET date

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

Should the following always match:

```
if(mydbrecord.DateField.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
{...}
```

where mydbrecord date is the current day?  I'm retrieving mydbrecord through linq-sql.

mydbrecord.DateField.Date is in the format '2013-12-19 00:00:00.000'.

Comment: Do your mydbrecord.DateField.Date value is Date only or it includes time?

Comment: I've updated the OP with the answer.

Comment: Ok your comparison won't be equal since current date have time value

Comment: If I do Convert.ToDatetime('2013-12-19 00:00:00.000'), they do equal.

Comment: see my posted answer and try.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx contains the mappings between the CLR and SQL types, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882657.aspx contains the methods supported by linq-to-sql for DateTime objects. Should absolutely be comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do it like this**

```
if(mydbrecord.DateField.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") == DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
{...}
```